# How can I connect to a Samba server using its hostname instead of the IP?

Tags: samba

I'm a beginner when it comes to Linux, and have recently put together a media server, holding all my movies, running Ubuntu 12.04.

After following tutorials and forums I can successfully ping, by hostname and IP, my windows desktop box and my media server Ubuntu box fine, and vice versa.

I've configured Samba to set up a share called Movies on my media server. I also set up an account on Samba using my Linux username, windows username with my Linux password.

My Ubuntu box is now visible on my network tree on my win7 box, as is the Movies share. however when I try to access the Movies share from the win7 box I do not have permission to do so.

I noticed that by using the static IP address I issued my Ubuntu media server, I can access the share with ease.

However I would like to be able to resolve the issue and access the share using the hostname of my Ubuntu media server box.

Sorry if I'm a bit unclear in my set up!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a couple of issues that could lead to this:

1. Enabling Netbios in your samba configuration file

   in your `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file, after the WORKGROUP line, add the following:
   `netbios name = PC_NAME` Where PC_NAME is the name of your PC as it will show in the network. Then reset the samba service `sudo service smbd restart`
2. Not having **STATIC IP**

   Need to have static IP set in order for other PCs on that network to see you. This also depends on your router and the configuration of your network.
3. Hostname length should be less than 15 characters

   If your hostname is longer than 15 characters it will give an error in some cases. Type `hostname` to see your hostname. To change it you can either:

   `sudo sysctl kernel.hostname=NAME`

   or you can edit the `/etc/hostname` file and reboot.
4. In the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file, look for the line that says the following:

   ```
   # What naming service and in what order should we use to resolve host names
   # to IP addresses
   ;   name resolve order = lmhosts host wins bcast
   ```

   Uncomment the line that says `name resolve order` and make sure that `bcast` is the first on in the list, should look like this afterwards:

   `name resolve order = bcast lmhosts host wins`

   Then restart the Samba service as I mentioned above.

This is all assuming it is Ubuntu the problem, you have already Samba installed and you are not working through Active Directory.

In many case it is also Windows. You would need to do stuff like flush the DNS and the register to it. On Windows in the terminal (cmd) do the following:

`ipconfig /flushdns`
`ipconfig /registerdns`

You need to reboot the PC afterwards. After this, check to see if you can see the Ubuntu PC by doing for example `net view` in Windows.

Comment: Fantastic reply Luis!! All I did was enter the netbios line with the name of my ubuntu box and it worked straight away - thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked, I put several options because depending on the network configuration, Windows version, how the router was set up, etc.. the solution might change. I know there are other options but this are the ones I have done over the years.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had to restart the nmbd service

```
sudo systemctl restart nmbd
```

Answer (score 2):

For me it was because my ubuntu was binding the hostname to IPv6 address, if you continue to face problems, the below article is worth a shot.

http://telsonalva.blogspot.in/2016/07/how-to-access-samba-share-in-linux-by.html

this worked for me