# Sharing files and devices between 2 Linux machines

Tags: networking, file-sharing, nfs, localhost

A couple of versions of Ubuntu ago, (guessing about 10.10, no later than 12.10) I used to open Nautilus, type in the local IP address of a Linux machine on my network, and it would pop open a box asking for user name and password, ask if I want to remember these credentials. Then right away I would have access to that computer's files reading and writing. I was even able to access a CD on Linux Computer #1, and play the Windows exe file using Wine on Linux Computer #2. Now I can't seem to do this on any of my recent installs. I havn't tried this on Ubuntu as I don't currnetly like how slow unity is on medium speed hardware. So I use Xubuntu 13.10 on my desktop now, and ElementaryOS Luna is what's on my laptop now.

I don't remember ever changing sharing options when it worked before, buts its possible I changed it and forgot or didn't know what that setting really did. I really would prefer a mostly graphical way to set this up. Something that is not at all dependant on distro or version, as I enjoy trying new things that come out, or even putting in one of my Old Ubuntu 9.04 CDs just for nostalgia reasons. (first version I ever used, and so easy and customizable, I really miss it :'(... )

I've heard of NFS and tried it but didn't work, and was way to text file and terminal oriented for my tastes. Want something rock solid that can't be messed up.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Murphy's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law)? If you want something that can't be messed up, steer well clear of computers.

Comment: Haha true, but some apps have been relatively rock solid, despite my enjoyment of distro hopping. Guake, Synapse (GnomeDo clone) GDebi installer, Xiphos Bible software. Love graphical Linux is lately, while still being solid. :-)

Comment: I recommend reading the following: http://askubuntu.com/questions/424722/heres-my-smb-conf-file-whats-wrong-with-it/424737#424737  http://askubuntu.com/questions/243461/how-can-i-connect-to-a-samba-server-using-its-hostname-instead-of-the-ip/243465#243465 and http://askubuntu.com/questions/7117/which-to-use-nfs-or-samba

Comment: Those are an interesting read. But between 2 Linux machines, Samba is not necessary as its intented to bridge between Windows and Linux, where Linux works natively.-----And though I could probably learn alot from reading about NFS, I know for sure I didn't go through all that with the older versions of Ubuntu, so things should be gettings easier newer versions, not harder. --------The only thing I might have done is right click on  a directory > Properties > Then seen a "Sharing" tab at the top, or maybe was under permission, then allowed for everything. All GUI. Why is this not standard???

Comment: No answer takers yet :-( I have tried all "flavors" of Ubuntu at this point, and none have been intuitive to connect to machines together in this way. Why??? I think its the year 2014 right? not 1994?