# SAMBA in UBUNTU 14.04

Tags: 14.04, printing, samba, windows-xp, shared-folders

I have  a small home network consisting of UBUNTU 12 and 14 and Win XP.  I was using samba well for local file and print share.

Until I upgraded to 14.04.  Now nothing works.  I have read all these forums and everything I can find on the internet and either none of it quite works as described or it requires a lot of terminal type knowledge - which I don’t have.

Is there a simple way to get shares working again like they did in 12.04.  Preferably via a GUI rather than too much deep terminal typing.

If even I could get the 14.04 machines to access files and printers on the 12.04 box that would be useful as a start.  They can see it but fail to retrieve the share list.

Or after an automatic prompted Samba install the 'files' window crashes on opening Workgroup.

There must be a simple way to achieve this?  No?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This GUI tool works well: "system-config-samba" http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/05/ubuntu1404-file-sharing-samba/

Comment: Ok.  I've loaded that tool on all my machines as per the instructions at the link.  One of the Ubuntu14 machines can see the other but not the other way around and neither of the 14 machines can see the Ubuntu 12 machine.  It seems a little inconsistent no?  Or is there something else I need to be doing?

Comment: Actually, which boxes can see others seems to vary day to day, but its never all around like expected.  And the 14 boxes can never read the 12 box.  Is there a way around that?

Comment: Have you tried to access the other machines by the IP number?  are you using hostnames shorter than 15 chars? may be this answer could help you: [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/243461/how-can-i-connect-to-a-samba-server-using-its-hostname-instead-of-the-ip)

Comment: IP number?  No, I've just tried to share folders on Samba and access them from other Pcs on the network, using 'Files'.  Like it all worked a treat in UBUNTU 12.04.  Now it doesn't work in 14.04.  I was wondering if there was something fundamental I was doing wrong?  I can try some of the things in that link above J.Serra thanks.  But it all refers to 12.04 when I had no problems anyway.  Do you think it may help with these 'new' 14.04 issues?

Comment: You can put the ip in the location bar of nautilus      smb://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/  pressing Ctrl+L you will see the location bar of nautilus (Ubuntu default file browser)

Comment: Thanks J.Serra, using IP address for access works! So maybe the Host name of the 'inaccessible' box (which was more than 15 chars)  was the fault?  I can look at that later, wither way I have a working method now.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This is an incomplete answer, and I apologize for that.

I have the same issue, and I'm too lazy to figure out what is going on. I think it may be related to the addition of samba-ad-dc.

I worked around this issue by starting smbd and nmbd manually instead of using the init system.

```
$ sudo smbd -D
$ sudo nmbd -D
```

Since I'm not using any other features, and this is my home server which is in UPS and does not reboot, this worked for me.