# User cant access samba from windows 8.1

Tags: windows, password, samba

```
[Open_Share]
path = /home/brady/open_share
available = yes
guest ok = yes
valid users = brady
read only = no
browseable = yes
public = yes
writable = yes
force user = brady
create mask = 0640
directory mask = 0750
```

I also have `security = user` in the `[Global]` section

My problem is when I try to access *Open_share* on a windows 8.1 laptop it asks for a password then keeps popping up with the password window. After a couple of tries Windows says "Open_share cannot be accessed". It says it can not find it. I set my brady user's password to test from samba. I can not tell if the password is wrong or if it can not find *Open_share*.

This is for a home server environment. So I am not strict on security. I just want to be able to access *Open_Share*. I even deleted `valid users = brady` and it still will not let me access it.

I have tried everything. Maybe there is something wrong with the path?

Answer (score 3):

I see you have practically tried everything. I recommend starting with a fresh copy of the smb.conf file. It should look something like this:

```
[global]
    workgroup = XTREME
    server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
    dns proxy = no
    force user = cyrex
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size = 1000
    syslog = 0
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    encrypt passwords = true
    obey pam restrictions = yes
    unix password sync = yes
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    pam password change = yes
    map to guest = bad user
    usershare allow guests = yes

[printers]
    comment = All Printers
    browseable = no
    path = /var/spool/samba
    printable = yes
    create mask = 0700

[print$]
    comment = Printer Drivers
    path = /var/lib/samba/printers

[movies]
    path = /media/cyrex/titan
    browseable = yes
    guest ok = yes
```

In this case I only have the movies share which I made. It works under Windows XP, 7 or 8. I added/modified the following options to the default `smb.conf` which do the following:

- `guest ok` = yes - This helps with the password issue.
- `force user = cyrex` - This also helps with the password issue and lets users see the content of the shared resource instead of only seeing the shared resource.
- `browseable = yes` - Will let users see the shared resource when navigating on the network.
- `workgroup = XTREME` - This is the workgroup on my LAN.

Notice I do not have any other attributes or permissions to make the example easier and as you mentioned, it is local so not much worry on security. After doing that I only did `sudo service smbd restart` to let samba read the new setup.

To create the original smb.conf do the following:

```
sudo cp -a /usr/share/samba/smb.conf /etc/samba/
```

You can find a bit more information about samba in:

[How can I connect to a Samba server using its hostname instead of the IP?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/243461/how-can-i-connect-to-a-samba-server-using-its-hostname-instead-of-the-ip/243465#243465)

[Here's my smb.conf file. Whats wrong with it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/424722/heres-my-smb-conf-file-whats-wrong-with-it/424737#424737)

Comment: Thank you Luis, my problem was that I changed the path and forgot to create the directory via mkdir ... You helped me find that. Thank you very much!